# Como poder visualizar resultados que vienen de un webservice y un dynamic que vienen con un .? ejemplo .expires

Tags: c#, json, rest

Estimada comunidad tengo una duda respecto a una forma de poder visualizar datos obtenidos del webservice que represento en los siguientes comandos y que ciertos parametros con el console.write no puedo lograr hacer que se visualicen siendo que me llegan resultados desde el webservice,

```
 IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        string jsonString = response.Content;
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        Console.ReadLine();

  dynamic jResult = 
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
        Console.WriteLine(jResult);
        Console.Write("AccessToken generado: "+jResult.access_token+ System.Environment.NewLine);
        Console.Write("TokenType generado: " + jResult.token_type+ System.Environment.NewLine);
        Console.Write("Expires in: " + jResult.expires_in + System.Environment.NewLine);
        Console.Write("Refresh Token: " + jResult.refresh_token + System.Environment.NewLine);
        Console.Write("as:client_id: " + jResult.client_id + System.Environment.NewLine);
        Console.Write("Username: " + jResult.username + System.Environment.NewLine);
        Console.Write("MachineName: " + jResult.machine_name + System.Environment.NewLine);
        Console.Write("Refresh: " + jResult.refresh.toString() + System.Environment.NewLine);
        Console.Write("Issued: " + jResult.issued + System.Environment.NewLine);
        Console.Write("Expires: " + jResult.expires + System.Environment.NewLine);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

El resultado generado es lo siguiente en una aplicacion de consola desde el webservice

```
{
     "access_token": "RzywoqAx-h9oOguAAok7Mfk8i1U=",
      "token_type": "bearer",
      "expires_in": 1199,
      "refresh_token": "5fr1Ovx1gMFKrgd_MZL7ndrOdas=",
      "as:client_id": "STG.RT.ThinClient.DocumentREST",
      "username": "Administrador",
      "machine_name": "STG.RT.ThinClient.DocumentREST",
      ".refresh": "True",
      ".issued": "Mon, 01 Jul 2019 19:05:26 GMT",
      ".expires": "Mon, 01 Jul 2019 19:25:26 GMT"
 }
```

Al momento de querer visualizar los resultados desde estas tres respuestas con los comandos expuestos anteriormente (Console.write) estos parametros que llegan del webservice me los deja en blanco, mostrando a modo de ejemplo pero aplicando el console.write:

```
"access_token": "RzywoqAx-h9oOguAAok7Mfk8i1U=",
"token_type": "bearer",
"expires_in": 1199,
"refresh_token": "5fr1Ovx1gMFKrgd_MZL7ndrOdas=",
"as:client_id": "STG.RT.ThinClient.DocumentREST",
"username": "Administrador",
"machine_name": "STG.RT.ThinClient.DocumentREST",
.refresh": "", (En blanco)
".issued": "", (En blanco)
".expires": "" (En blanco)
```

Saben que podria ser el error de porque no me muestra las variables mencionadas al aplicar el console.write? dejo los comandos que no me muestran los resultados que se mencionan para que puedan entender mi duda.

```
Console.Write("Refresh: " + jResult.refresh.toString() + System.Environment.NewLine);
Console.Write("Issued: " + jResult.issued + System.Environment.NewLine);
Console.Write("Expires: " + jResult.expires + System.Environment.NewLine);
```

Muchas gracias y saludos a todos en la comunidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te ayudas con

http://json2csharp.com/

al pones el json veras que obtienes una clase como ser:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public string token_type { get; set; }
    public int expires_in { get; set; }
    public string refresh_token { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__as:client_id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string machine_name { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__.refresh { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__.issued { get; set; }
    public string __invalid_name__.expires { get; set; }
}
```

observaras que la conversion esta marcando que estos valor con `.` punto no los reconoce como validos

Entiendo que al poner un punto delante estaria marcando una propiedad privada

Pero en principio no puedes acceder porque no es valido para un json

---

Implemente el siguiente ejemplo

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string jsonString = @"{
                                 'access_token': 'RzywoqAx-h9oOguAAok7Mfk8i1U=',
                                  'token_type': 'bearer',
                                  'expires_in': 1199,
                                  'refresh_token': '5fr1Ovx1gMFKrgd_MZL7ndrOdas=',
                                  'as:client_id': 'STG.RT.ThinClient.DocumentREST',
                                  'username': 'Administrador',
                                  'machine_name': 'STG.RT.ThinClient.DocumentREST',
                                  '.refresh': 'True',
                                  '.issued': 'Mon, 01 Jul 2019 19:05:26 GMT',
                                  '.expires': 'Mon, 01 Jul 2019 19:25:26 GMT'
                             }";

        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
        Console.WriteLine(result.issued);

    }
}
```

Utilizando la clase con el atributo `[JsonProperty]` y funciona

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public string token_type { get; set; }
    public int expires_in { get; set; }
    public string refresh_token { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("as:client_id")]
    public string client_id { get; set; }

    public string username { get; set; }
    public string machine_name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(".refresh")]
    public string refresh { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(".issued")]
    public string issued { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(".expires")]
    public string expires { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Don Leandro Muy buenas Noches, solo lo que aparece sin invalid se entiende que son los parámetros que puedo utilizar cierto?

Comment: edite la respuesta consiguiendo acceder a esas propiedades

Comment: Muchas gracias don Leandro.